# g++ autovectorization fail for the most basic example

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, compiler-optimization, vectorization

I am currently trying to use autovectorization with g++.
To do so, I use the following minimal example:

```
#include <array>
int main()
{
    std::array<double, 16> x;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 16; i++) x[i] = i;
    return x[15];
}
```

And I compile with:

```
g++-4.7 -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -O3 -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=9 tests.cpp -o tests
```

And the result is:

```
Analyzing loop at tests.cpp:5

5: ===== analyze_loop_nest =====
5: === vect_analyze_loop_form ===
5: === get_loop_niters ===
5: ==> get_loop_niters:16
5: === vect_analyze_data_refs ===

5: not vectorized: no vectype for stmt: MEM[(value_type &)&x]._M_instance[i_21] = D.21296_5;
 scalar_type: value_type
5: bad data references.
tests.cpp:2: note: vectorized 0 loops in function.
```

What is the problem and how to solve it ?

EDIT:
and the result is the same for:

```
#include <array>
int main()
{
    std::array<int, 16> x;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) x[i] = i;
    return x[15];
}
```

Comment: is `x[i] = i` really something that can be vectorized? Maybe you should try something along the lines of `x[i] = a[i] + b[i]`.

Comment: g++ 4.7.2 successfully vectorizes the loop for me. Have you looked at the resulting assembly output?

Comment: This whole functions looks like something which should get optimized to `return 15;` without any vectorization.

Comment: What is your exact platform/compiler combination? Seems to vectorize just fine for g++4.7.2 under x86-64

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your compile flags `no vectype for stmt` means that your architecture doesn't support these instructions.

Set `-march=native` or `-march=corei7`

Comment: Works fine with `-march=corei7`. Note: I'm under VirtualBox (Host: Win7 x64, Guest: Ubuntu 12.04 with g++4.7.1)